# What causes "subscript out of bounds" when using doParallel

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, doparallel

I am using the [MethylMix](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/MethylMix/inst/doc/vignettes.html) package, which requires equal rowlength for `KIRP.meth`, `KIRP.mrna`, and `normal.meth`. My code raised "subscript out of bounds" error.

```
library(MethylMix)

cl <- makeCluster(10)
registerDoParallel(cl)
MethylMixResults <- MethylMix(METcancer=KIRP.meth, GEcancer=KIRP.mrna, METnormal=normal.meth)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Traceback:

```
Found 173 samples with both methylation and expression data.
Correlating methylation data with gene expression...
Error in { : task 27 failed - "subscript out of bounds"
```

Input:

```
> dim(KIRP.meth)
[1] 15303   173
> dim(KIRP.mrna)
[1] 15303   173
> dim(normal.meth)
[1] 15303    45


> dput(KIRP.meth[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.600779057354644, 0.655777740723865, 0.815910290849851, 
0.910945855401136, 0.134190006466966, 0.37318608461713, 0.49246343888403, 
0.794749348441249, 0.881573960745319, 0.0964743163693759, 0.492598954289208, 
0.49246343888403, 0.640456271154751, 0.923089664076206, 0.0793144655277971, 
0.409032309692879, 0.49246343888403, 0.846665808683809, 0.887081977280946, 
0.0992061641604958, 0.248944186060665, 0.682773900167259, 0.862532922981447, 
0.931424455647269, 0.0554991951237877), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A4GALT"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01")))

> dput(KIRP.mrna[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(2.59432624081245, 0.954242509439325, 4.60945801720877, 
0, 3.41229250932305, 1.84453930212901, 1.88081359228079, 4.04178850233385, 
0, 3.67403400043125, 1.86272752831797, 1.46239799789896, 3.50267151256675, 
0, 3.44232295574557, 1.85381984585676, 2.30102999566398, 3.92471233053849, 
0, 3.5585885831082, 2.37145578191302, 1, 3.57821043337005, 0.698970004336019, 
3.4679039465228), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(c("A1BG", 
"A1CF", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A4GALT"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01")))

> dput(normal.meth[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.349328212624544, 0.64070562208869, 0.827770814068351, 
0.905037869297127, 0.0927688497941891, 0.386231521358919, 0.825015074989356, 
0.772426622237963, 0.895876334199358, 0.151047955966834, 0.36338160144188, 
0.637276378504495, 0.806073475591881, 0.888988587975131, 0.0689215903518559, 
0.304882343721657, 0.650016439361786, 0.809938291034322, 0.880177371770518, 
0.0705074131312755, 0.452569562949796, 0.59748205175223, 0.852044340187524, 
0.904803008777971, 0.0872863750860763), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A4GALT"), c("TCGA.A4.7288.11", 
    "TCGA.BQ.5880.11", "TCGA.BQ.5879.11", "TCGA.BQ.5883.11", 
    "TCGA.BQ.7055.11")))
```